# Pervasive psql backup and restore

Tags: pervasive-sql

I am trying to find any free method possible to restore a backup file to Pervasive SQL tables.

I have downloaded pervasive server and the backup agent .

Can anyone help me

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because the Pervasivse SQL tables are stored in individual files, backing up can be as simple as copying the files to another location.  Restoring is the just as easy by copying the backup over the existing file.

If the files are always open, you can use [Continuous Operation](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=advops/backup.09.5.html#83694) mode.  You don't need Backup Agent to use Continuous Operation mode.

Comment: 2nd this.  "Backup" for us has always meant that we create a ZIP archive that includes everything in the database folder.  "Restore" then means simply unzipping the archive into an existing database folder.